# Any messaging queue - FIFO requirement

Tags: message-queue, messaging

Question on messaging queues. I've been reading around for a while (couple of days) on the number of messaging queue products - totally astounding!

I need to have the ability to have FIFO in a queue. and i read that the messaging product guarantee delivery but not FIFO.

Any ideas on possible messaging implementations that guarantee FIFO? Or any other implementation ideas that don't use messaging systems?

Answer (score 3):

ActiveMQ guarrantees the message order of all messages sent by the same producer but also supports total ordering. For an example how to configure total ordering take a look at the documentation:

http://activemq.apache.org/total-ordering.html